# what does it mean for a curve to be the union of two curves?

Tags: calculus

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNXw4.png

Question 2a asks for the length of C, but what does it mean for a curve to be the union of two curves? Is it just a curve defined by $cos(t)=1+t-2\pi$ and $sin(t)=0$? How would you go about finding the length of something like that?

And for question 1a, should I be calculating the integral of the norm of the derivative from $0$ or from $3\pi/2$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**

*How to interpret the curves:*

Imagine driving along a path defined by $C_1$ for time $[3\pi/2, 2\pi]$. Then it ends and you drive with a new set of directions $C_2$ from $[2\pi, 2\pi +1]$. Note that both paths equal (1,0) at $2\pi$, so $C_1$ feeds right into $C_2$.

*To compute the length of each curve, you need to calculate the arclength:*

$$L = \int ds^2  = \int_{x=a}^{b} \sqrt{dx^2+dy^2} = \int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{1+(\frac{dy}{dx})^2} dx$$

*To use the parameter $t$ with the above equation, you can apply the chain rule.*

$$L= \int_{t=t_o}^{t_f} \sqrt{1+(\frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt})^2} \frac{dx}{dt}dt$$